# Selected value in Select statement using 'options' in knockout js

Tags: json, knockout.js

I'm trying to submit a form using Knockout JS as, that data is passed as json. Here I'm having a problem. The following is my KO model.

```
var permissionRequestModel = {

fromDate: ko.observable(''),
toDate: ko.observable(''),
checkFullDay: ko.observable(false),

fromTimeHH: ko.observable(''),
fromTimeMM: ko.observable(''),
toTimeHH: ko.observable(''),
toTimeMM: ko.observable(''),

permissionTypeOne: ko.observable(''),
permissionTypeTwo: ko.observable(''),

approverList: ko.observableArray([]),

reasonLeave: ko.observable('')

};
```

Now in this approverList is being populated by an Array taken from a retrieved json object, its populted as follows

```
$(function () {
$.getJSON("http://ec20032432.compute-1.amazonaws.com/api/Request/permission?appid=1&opertype=get_approver_list", function (data) { permissionRequestModel.approverList(data.Approvers); })
});
```

the retrived data.Approvers will be of the form:

```
"Approvers":
[{"ID":"asdasd",
 "Display_Name":"Jason asdasd"}]
```

I need the text of the dropdown list to be the 'Display_Name' and Value to be 'ID', so I use the following markup to do it:

```
 <select name="approverList" id="approverList" data-native-menu="true" class="required" data-bind="options: approverList, optionsCaption: 'Select Your Approver', optionsText: 'Display_Name', optionsValue:'ID'">
                    </select>
```

So far its fine, but now when I submit the form using the following code, the approverList us being passed as an object instead of the selected value (ie the ID):

```
permissionRequestModel.requestPermission = function () {
if ($("#permissionRequestForm").valid()) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://eertretetrer.compute-1.amazonaws.com/api/Request/permission?appid=1&opertype=requestor",
        type: "POST",
        data: ko.toJSON(permissionRequestModel),
        processData:false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function (result) {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert(result.responseText);
        }
     });
}
else {
}
};
```

Does anybody know why this is happening? How do I send the value instead (of ID)?

Comment: Do you want to pass value as for example "DH130618"? Right now what are you getting ko.toJSON(permissionRequestModel)?

Comment: yes thats what I want to pass. Right now approverList is being passed as an object which is being taken as a null value I guess.

Comment: Do you want to pass whole view model to json? Even i am new to knockout but i know other way to send data to json.

Comment: Also can you tell me what output you get in data?

Comment: in data approverList: object[0], this object contains the whole list of approvers returned initially, when actually only the selected value is what I want.

Comment: if you are ok to send values one by one instead of sending whole view model then i can suggest you to add one more observable called self.ApproverId = ko.observable();. Then in your html bind like 
<select name="approverList" id="approverList" data-native-menu="true" class="required" data-bind="options: approverList, optionsCaption: 'Select Your Approver', optionsText: 'Display_Name', value:ApproverId"></select>    

Then when you send data you have to send individual elements and pass value like self.ApproverId().ID();

did you got it?

Comment: @AshReva You are right, I just added a new ko.observable property and named it approverList and changed the name of the observable array, then added the value property and assigned the new approverList to it and passed it like before(whole thing as json) & it worked, sending one by one is not required. But thanks anyhow :) can you write it as an answer so that I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add one more observable called

```
self.ApproverId = ko.observable();
```

Then in your html bind like

```
<select name="approverList" id="approverList" data-native-menu="true" class="required" data-bind="options: approverList, optionsCaption: 'Select Your Approver', optionsText: 'Display_Name', value:ApproverId"></select>
```

I hope this helps